# trying to find the position of the elemet using selenium in python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, webdriver

```
quem_esta_sacando = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='gameinfo-container tennis-container']/div[@class='team-names']/div[@class='team-name']")
```

> this is how i found the right class, but i wanna find the order of it

```
<div class="gameinfo-container tennis-container">
    <div class="team-names">
        <div class="team-name">
            <img alt="ball">
        <div class="team-name">
            <img alt="ball" class="active">
```

> the last class (active) may change during the time it passes, so, sometimes its will be like the first, but sometimes it will be like this:

```
<div class="gameinfo-container tennis-container">
    <div class="team-names">
        <div class="team-name">
            <img alt="ball" class="active">
        <div class="team-name">
            <img alt="ball">
```

> i wanna know, without looking every time, who come first

> i try to use this:

```
if active in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='gameinfo-container tennis-container']/div[@class='team-names']/div[@class='team-name'][last()]").get_attribute("class"):
    print("last element")
else:
    print("Wasn't the last element")
```

> but it's became that the name "active" isn't defined

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to take the element that has the `active` class ?

Comment: i want to see if the class="active" is in the first or in the second team-name

Answer (score 0):

As per the probhable actual html:

```
<div class="gameinfo-container tennis-container">
    <div class="team-names">
    <div class="team-name">
        <img alt="ball">
    <div class="team-name">
        <img alt="ball" class="active">
```

You can probe the last matching [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139), if it's *outerHTML* or *class* contains the value **active** and you can use either of the following approaches:

- Probing the *outerHTML*:

  ```
  if active in driver.find_element_by_xpath("///div[@class='gameinfo-container tennis-container']/div[@class='team-names']//div[@class='team-name'][last()]/img[@alt='ball']").get_attribute("outerHTML"):
      print("last element")
  else:
      print("Wasn't the last element")
  ```
- Probing the *classname*:

  ```
  if active in driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='gameinfo-container tennis-container']/div[@class='team-names']//div[@class='team-name'][last()]/img[@alt='ball']").get_attribute("class"):
      print("last element")
  else:
      print("Wasn't the last element")
  ```

Comment: i think it is right, all the logic make sense, but when i try to run it, thats the error becames to me: global name 'active' is not defined

Comment: @caleulraposocaixeta My bad, I posted an untested solution as the html you provided was syntactically not 100% correct and I wanted to preserve your working [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890). Updated the answer now, let me know the status.